# ReactJs input first value getting empty

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[console log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJHvK.png)

I'm getting first input value empty. I have different app. I'm basically try to doing tip calculator app. I don't need submit button. The user will enter a value, but it does not calculate correctly because the first value is empty. At the same time, it does not show the last value entered, only when clicked, all the entered values are correct.  By the way, i got this form from React own site, but it's the same error that i encountered. Thank you!

Comment: put console.log(this.state.value); into render to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log` logs the value before you change it. Thus it will always be the previous value.

You also have to keep in mind that the `Component.setState` method might not execute immediately.

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Therefore you should use a [`callback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). E.g.

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.value);
  });
}
```

Here is an executable example. Click **Run code snippet**.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.value);
      });
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set initial value to `0` so that it will not be empty.

```
this.state = { value: 0 };
```

Also move your `console.log` as callback function to `setState` so that you can see the updated value.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.value);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code but still same. https://ibb.co/BZ2SCgQ -- like when i write number 3 I can't get 3 at same time.

Comment: its working for me correctly. let me post complete component code for you